# finding a normal basis for infinite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I was reading this one: [www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hwl/PUBLICATIONS/1985c/art.pdf](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hwl/PUBLICATIONS/1985c/art.pdf)

First page, the converse part is not clear to me.  Also this is the paper for normal basis for infinite Galois, then at the starting of the 3 rd paragraph [image]
 why it is written "Let L be finite..." ? I have high-lightened my two doubts. I am not able to show that $\{\sigma(x)\}_ {\sigma \in G}$ forms a basis.The linearly independent part follows from Dedekind's theorem for linearly independent characters.

Comment: Finite over $K$ means that $L$ is finite dimensional as a vector space over $K$.

Comment: Short answer: $(\sigma(x))_{\sigma \in G}$ is the image of a basis for $(G,K)$ under a linear isomorphism, so it is a basis.

Comment: Is it true if $L/K$ not finite?

Comment: Nope.  No finite subset of $L$ would be a basis for $L/K$ in that case.  And for fixed $x \in L$, $\{ \sigma(x) : \sigma \in G\}$ is finite, because $\sigma$ just sends $x$ to other roots of its minimal polynomial over $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think about it this way.  Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension of degree $n$, and let $G = \textrm{Gal}(L/K)$.  Let $X_g$ be some symbol, one for each $g \in G$. Then you can define a vector space $V$ with formal basis $X_g : g \in G$.  There is a group action of $G$ on $V$, defined on the basis elements $X_g$ by $h \cdot X_g = X_{hg}$.  This action distributes over vector addition and scalar multiplication.

At the same time, there is a group action of $G$ on the vector space $L$ (like $V$, $L$ is a vector space over $K$ of dimension $n$)., given by evaluation.  Since the elements of $G$ are automorphisms of $L$ which fix $K$, they also distribute over addition and scalar multiplication.  The goal is to construct a vector space isomorphism $\phi: V \rightarrow L$ with the property that $g( \phi(v)) = \phi(g \cdot v)$ for all $v \in V, g \in G$.

Now $1_L \in G$ is the identity element of $G$.  It follows that if you take the element $X_{1_G} \in V$, and the given $\phi$, then $x := \phi(X_{1_G})$ is the required element for the normal basis.  Indeed, let $G = \{g_1 = 1_L, g_2, ... , g_n\}$.  We know that $$\{1_L X_{1_L}, g_2  X_{1_L}, ... , g_n X_{1_L} \} = \{ X_{1_L}, X_{g_2}, ... , X_{g_n} \}$$ is a basis for $V$.  Hence $\phi$ maps this basis to a basis of $L/K$.  But $\phi(g_i X_{L_i}) = g_i(\phi(X_{L_i})) = g_i(x)$, so $g_1(x), ... , g_n(x)$ (that is, $g(x) : g \in G$) is a basis for $L/K$, as required.